# posting data into the database using $_GET

Tags: php, html, mysql

url - addreview.php?name=mercury

This is what the form looks like

```
<form action="addreviewaction.php" method="post" name="addReview">
<textarea name="content" cols="45" rows="7"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="clubname" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm trying to post data into the database using this

```
<?php

$tbl_name="reviews"; // Switch to table "reviews"

// get data thats sent from the form 
$content=$_POST['content'];
$clubname=$_POST['clubname'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(content, clubname)VALUES('$content','$clubname')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

But I get errors where its not getting inserted in the database. How can I solve this?

Comment: You're how old and you need to be told that we're not psychic? What errors?

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and that may very well be causing your errors.  Use prepared/parameterized queries, or **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Also, you have opened yourself up to XSS attacks!  Use `htmlspecialchars()` around any arbitrary data used in the context of HTML.  (In your case, that's `$_GET['name']`).

Comment: Im currently working on my localhost this for personal use.

Comment: Also post your errors.

Comment: I expect you're getting errors from MySQL when the text typed into the form includes one or more quotation marks. Perhaps `$content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);` will fix this. But **please** take @Brad's advice. And start using PHP's [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) functions; the `mysql_query()` function is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL is wrong.
***"INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(content, clubname, firstname)VALUES('$content',     '$clubname')***

You have provided 3 column names(content, clubname, firstname), but entering values for only 2 columns(content, clubname).. Value for "**firstname**" is missing.

Thanks

Comment: I made some changes to the code... Ignore firstname.

Comment: Does it work now ?? or still it's returning error's ??

Comment: I guess the error is still related to SQL query. Your query will hit the DB, expecting the table name to be $tbl_name. You have to modify your query to provide the table name dynamically, using the concept of prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually posting to this file and you are connected to a database...

```
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (`content`, `clubname`) VALUES ('$content','$clubname')";
```

You never defined firstname but you are expecting it to insert it, then not specifying what to insert. The mismatched expectations will error.

You are not escaping anything here. Wide open for sql injections. Switch to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements. mysql_ functions are deprecated.

Comment: For now this for personal use... Working on this on the localhost. Ignore firstname pasted the code in by mistake.

Comment: what errors are you getting?